# AngularJs giving me a hard time trying to fetch twitter timeline

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the following piece of trying to fetch some tweets for a timeline. This is the same code what was used in AngularJS tutorial. It worked fine with twitter's search API.

```
angular.module( 'Twitter', [ 'ngResource' ]); 

function TwitterCtrl( $scope, $resource )
{ 
  $scope.twit = $resource( 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/:action',
  {
    action: 'user_timeline.json',
    screen_name: 'jesus',
    count: '6',
    include_rts: '1',
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
  }, { get:{method:'JSONP' }});

  $scope.twit.get();
}
```

But now I changed the code to fetch from a timeline and it is giving me some problems. It looks like AngularJS is looking for an array where there is none. Anyone knows what going on here?

```
TypeError: Object #<e> has no method 'push'
    at copy (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:556:21)
    at f.module.factory.e.(anonymous function) (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular-resource.min.js:8:242)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:6628:59)
    at ref.then (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:6665:26)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:7813:28)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:7685:25)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:7899:24)
    at done (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:8891:20)
    at completeRequest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:9035:7)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js:8981:11
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should add `isArray: true` in the definition of 'get'.

Comment: Oh wow! I saw isArray in the docs as a parameter of query. Right now I changed the code to work with $http, which seems to do the job. I'll try your suggestion tonight or tomorrow. See or that does the trick.